# Quais as implicações de não declarar variáveis em PHP?

Tags: php, declaração-de-variável

Em php posso fazer isto sem declarar/defenir variáveis:

```php
echo($foo);  //resolve: vazio, sem nada
$foo++;
echo($foo);  // resolve: 1
```

Usando `var_dump()` o mesmo dá, respectivamente `NULL` e `1`.
Se eu usar `settype($foo, "integer");` antes , o mesmo dá `0`e `1`.

A questão é, existe alguma implicação de performance,utilização ou outra que justifique evitar estas utilizações:

```php
//usar um contador sem o defenir ou resetar primeiro
$foo++;

// adicionar elementos a uma array 
// sem os defenir $bar = array('2010'=>0,'2011'=>0); primeiro
$bar['2010']++; 
$bar['2010']++;
$bar['2011']++;  // ou $bar['2011'] = 'blah';
// resolve: array(2) { [2010]=> int(2) [2011]=> int(1) }
```

Comment: Por mais que seja poético, concordo que a edição permitiu a pergunta ficar mais clara. Não vou responder a pergunta porque não é o que você espera, mas você deve fazer sempre o que é mais legível, que indique melhor a intenção, e declarar variáveis, mesmo que não seja necessário, é uma forma de legibilidade e contenção de bugs misteriosos. Performance deve ser a última preocupação, em geral quase nunca em se tratando de PHP.

Comment: Para uma atualização desta discussão:
As variáveis não foram oficialmente regulamentadas em nenhuma PSR, que na minha opinião, deveria estar em [PSR-1](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1 "Codificação Básica") e [PSR-2](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2 "Estilo de codificação") Portanto, boas práticas / performance / uso, vai do programador, ao meu ver. Gostei de todas as respostas dadas aqui, mas, tudo depende mesmo da necessidade do programa.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Estritamente falando, não há declaração de variáveis em PHP. Ou seja, não há na linguagem um *statement* como `var` para que se declare variáveis. Na prática, as variáveis são **inicializadas** no primeiro uso. Segundo o [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.variables.basics.php):

> Não é necessário variáveis inicializadas [sic; seria *incializar variáveis*] no PHP, contudo é uma ótima prática. Variáveis não inicializadas tem [sic; *têm*] um valor padrão do tipo dela dependendo do contexto no qual eles são usados [sic; *elas são usadas*] - [o] padrão de booleanos é FALSE, de inteiros e ponto-flutuantes é zero, strings (e.g. usado em echo) são definidos como uma string vazia e arrays tornam-se um array vazio.

<sup>Como podem ver, a tradução do manual é uma porcaria</sup>

Portanto:

```php
$foo = 1; // inicializa a variável e atribui valor 1
$bar++;   // inicializa a variável, e por inferência de tipos ela é
          // inicializada como 0 antes de ser incrementada
```

Como disse e o @elias, e também o manual, a segunda forma não é considerada boa prática, embora funcione. O ideal é deixar as inicializações claras, de maneira padronizada (antes do primeiro uso, ou talvez no topo do escopo), para que o código fique mais claro para quem lê.

Comment: O que é esse 'foo' e 'bar' que tanto vejo por aí?

Comment: @JoaoPaulo São nomes que se usam em exemplos para variáveis quaisquer, como X e Y. Ver (em inglês) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foobar

Answer (score 20):

Consigo enumerar alguns problemas de robustez, compatibilidade e futura manutenção que vão surgir quando estamos a trabalhar sem declarar as variáveis antes de as utilizar:

1. **Avisos em PHP** <sup>compatibilidade, robustez, futura manutenção</sup>

   Se o trabalho desenvolvido for parar a um servidor que contém o [error_reporting()](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.error-reporting.php) (relatório de erros) configurado para apresentar `E_NOTICE`, vamos estar a receber avisos de variáveis que estão a ser utilizadas sem primeiro terem sido declaradas.

   ```php
   // Reportar E_NOTICE pode ser muito bom (para reportar variáveis ​​
   // não inicializadas ou apanhar erros de digitação nos nomes das variáveis ​​...)
   error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_NOTICE);
   ```

   Isto é particularmente importante se o trabalho que desenvolvemos vai ser entregue a outra equipa ou ao nosso cliente para implementação. Também importante quando o servidor é gerido por uma pessoa que deixa os relatórios de erros ativados por defeito ao invés de ser a aplicação a solicitar os mesmos.

   Exemplo do erro obtido:

   ```php
   Notice: Undefined variable: banana in /john/doe/meu_ficheiro.php on line 4
   ```
2. **Utilização de variáveis com o mesmo nome** <sup>robustez, futura manutenção</sup>

   Neste exemplo, estamos a utilizar a variável, e muitas horas de trabalho depois voltamos a utilizar a mesma variável. Como não declaramos a mesma, ela está já com um valor atribuído, o que nos vai fazer perder muito tempo a descobrir porque é que a aplicação nos está a apresentar um resultado diferente do que esperávamos.

   ```php
   <?php

   // linha nº 25 do nosso ficheiro
   // valor da variável banana vem de base de dados por exemplo
   $banana = 100;

   for ($i = 1; $i <= $banana; $i++) {
     echo "O macaco comeu a banana nº ".$i;
   }


   // linha nº 1200 do nosso ficheiro
   // temos que trabalhar novamente bananas, então
   $macacos = recolheMacacos();

   while ($macacos <= $controloQualquer) {
       $banana++;
   }

   ?>
   ```

   Em alguns casos, cenários como este estão dentro de uma operação tão complexa que podem passar para produção, causando bem mais que uma simples perda de tempo.
3. **Troca do nome da variável** <sup>robustez, futura manutenção</sup>

   Muitas vezes estamos a escrever algo e a pensar noutra coisa, dando origem a que o texto escrito fique sujeito a erros. Declarar a variável em conjunto com os avisos de PHP ajudam-nos a desenvolver a aplicação sem deixar passar coisas deste género:

   ```php
   <?php

   // linha nº 25 do nosso ficheiro
   // recolha do stock das bananas
   $banana = novoStock('bananas');


   // linha nº 1200 do nosso ficheiro
   // adicionar ao stock mais bananas que chegaram
   $stock = incrementaStock($baanna);


   // apresenta novo stock ao utilizador
   echo "Stock atual: " . $sock;

   ?>
   ```

   Se a variável estiver declarada, sabemos que: ou recebemos o valor declarado ou o valor resultante das operações realizadas. 
   Se tivermos ativado os avisos de PHP no decorrer do desenvolvimento da nossa aplicação, vão ser alertados para o facto de que `$baanna`, `$sock` não estão declaradas e rapidamente resolvemos a questão.

---

#### Rapidez de execução (Performance)

Aqui é difícil chegar a um consenso dado que são muitas as variáveis que contribuem para isto. 
<sup>Mas se conseguir lembrar-me de um exemplo prático, editarei a resposta.</sup>

Answer (score 17):

Simplesmente declare-a.

Qualquer impacto na performance é irrelevante perto do impacto na manutenção.

Você ou outra pessoa pode chegar nesse trecho de código depois e não ter certeza se ele está certo porque não tem certeza de onde vem o valor da variável (é uma global? foi copiado de outro lugar e esqueceram de inicializar? ou escreveram assim mesmo desde o começo?).

Inicializar todas as suas variáveis é um jeito fácil de **comunicar a intenção** do seu código para os outros, faça isso. Além de ficar mais claro, você provavelmente estará evitando erros (seus e de colegas) -- por exemplo, alguém pode criar uma variável global com o mesmo nome e interferir no funcionamento do seu código.

Answer (score 13):

## Impacto na performance

Como muitos já disseram, dificilmente haverá um impacto relevante na performance.

Haverá ganhos muito maiores de desempenho criando algoritmos melhores, usando cache de *opcode* e outras técnicas nesse sentido.

## Impacto na manutenibilidade

Declarar variáveis aumenta e legibilidade do código, por consequência, a facilidade de você mesmo ou um colega entender o que foi implementado posteriormente.

## Impacto na qualidade

A qualidade interna e externa do sistema melhora por diversas razões:

- Aumenta o entendimento do código
- Evita bugs ocultos pelo uso de variáveis não inicializadas (será que sempre podemos confiar que operações com variáveis `undefined` sempre serão como esperamos?)
- Ajuda a pensarmos melhor no propósito das variáveis, diminuindo a incidência de variáveis com nomes ruins e genéricos. Esse é um conceito subjetivo, mas uma boa prática facilita as demais.

## Boas práticas correlatas

- Declare variáveis com nomes intuitivos, evitando usar explicações em comentários. Muitos comentários deixam o código poluído.
- Evite reusar variáveis "genéricas" (`$aux`) em vários pontos do código. É quase o mesmo que não declarar. Isso dificulta muito o entendimento para quem está lendo o código, já que é necessário ler todo o código para entender onde um "bloco de uso" começa e onde termina.
- Use variáveis no menor escopo possível, pois haverá menos confusão de valores que são alterados inadvertidamente, da lógica de um método interferindo em valores globais usados em outro método, etc. Tenha poucas variáveis globais e as lógicas importantes encapsuladas em métodos com variáveis locais ou, no máximo, usando atributos privados da classe.

Answer (score 6):

Acredito que a melhor forma seria declarar a variável antes de usá-la pois no futuro poderá evitar possíveis dores-de-cabeça ao fazer alguma edição ou implementação no código...  Até porque outras linguagens obrigam a declaração de variáveis antes de utilizá-las.

Answer (score 4):

Os mais experientes dizem que é bom declarar variáveis por inúmeros motivos. Pessoalmente, nunca tive problemas em não declarar variáveis, exceto por falta de atenção. Na maioria dos casos, os erros supracitados (nome de variável digitado errado, uso de variável que não está "zerada") estão sujeitos de acontecer, mesmo com declaração de variáveis.

Quanto à manutenção, declarar variáveis só me faz ter que refatorar mais código. Se o processo for auxiliado por uma IDE, sem problemas. Em linguagens como C e Java, já cometi erros de declaração de variáveis, que não ocorreriam se não precisasse declará-las.

Em determinadas ocasiões, eu opto por declarar variáveis em PHP, quando isso facilitar a leitura do código por outro colega de equipe. Fora isso, não vejo outras implicações positivas ou negativas para não declarar variáveis.

Answer (score 3):

Em geral, não há implicação nenhuma. O PHP é uma linguagem de tipagem fraca. Geralmente nas linguagens onde se devem declarar os tipos são necessário a declaração das mesmas. Outro caso é o javascript, pois a declaração da mesma pode implicar em qual escopo você a está usando.

No PHP, eu tomaria cuidado em casos de declaração de variável, apenas para deixar o programador atento para o que o código está fazendo.

Um caso que creio que seja necessário "declarar" a variável no PHP seria, por exemplo, na utilização de uma variável por referência quando se usa uma Closure, para não deixar o programador (que não conhece seu código) confuso

Exemplo que considero confuso:

```
DB::transaction(function () use(&$usuario) {
    $usuario = new Usuario(array('nome' => 'wallace');
});

print_r($usuario); // Usuario (object) {}
```

Exemplo que considero legível

```
$usuario; // Ou NULL

DB::transaction(function () use(&$usuario) {
    $usuario = new Usuario(array('nome' => 'wallace');
});

print_r($usuario); // Usuario (object) {}
```

Outra questão é que, no PHP, geralmente é realmente necessário declarar uma variável quando se trata de uma variável global.

Assim:

```
function counter()
{
    global $counter; // Declarei
    $conter = 0;
}
```