# include_once não tem acesso a propriedades, variáveis ou funções do arquivo incluido

Tags: php

Estou criando um arquivo genérico onde vários sistemas consigam usar as mesmas bibliotecas, assim gerando um pacote muito menor. Nesse arquivo genérico existe uma função onde eu faço os includes dos arquivos necessários. O problema que está ocorrendo, é que quando eu faço os includes dos sistemas nessa função, eu não tenho acesso as propriedades, variáveis e funções do arquivo incluido. Vou tentar exemplificar com a estrutura do sistema.

A estrutura do sistema é:

- `wamp/www/sistem/exemploSistema/index.php`
- `wamp/www/sistem/exemploSistema/funcoes.php`
- `wamp/www/sistem/generics/funcaoGenerica.php`

Arquivo `funcoes.php`:

```
<?
   $tt = 'teste';
   function teste(){
       global $tt;
       return $tt;
   }
?>
```

Arquivo `funcaoGenerica.php`:

```
<?php
    function generic($sting){
        include_once($sting);
    }
?>
```

Arquivo `index.php`:

```
<?
   include_once('/sistem/generics/funcaoGenerica.php');
   generic('/sistem/exemploSistema/funcoes.php');
   echo teste();
?>
```

No arquivo `index.php` eu não consigo ter acesso a função `teste` do arquivo `funcoes.php`. Teria alguma solução para esse problema ou alguma outra forma para o mesmo?

Comment: troca o `include_once` por um `required_once` e ve se gera algum erro.

Comment: Mostra alguma mensagem de erro? Troque `<?` por `<?php`

Comment: não aparece nenhum erro, apenas me volta vazio!

Comment: Funciona se você colocar  `include_once('/sistem/exemploSistema/funcoes.php');` ao inves de `generic('/sistem/exemploSistema/funcoes.php');`?

Comment: Trocou o que falei?

Answer (score 2):

É um problema de escopo. `$tt` tem que ser declarada como global na função `generic` dentro de `funcaoGenerica.php`.

```
function generic($sting){
    global $tt;
    include_once($sting);
}
```

Desconfio que tem algum jeito mais elegante de fazer isso, mas não saberia dizer agora... Achei uns tópicos ligeiramente relacionados, mas com material interessante:

- [Quais as implicações de não declarar variáveis em PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/841/201)
- [O que usar require/include/require_once/include_once?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15286/201)

Answer (score 0):

Numa função normal o `include` ou o `require` tem escopo de variável ou seja, o arquivo apenas fica disponível dentro do escopo da função que o chama.

> When a file is included, the code it contains inherits the variable
>   scope of the line on which the include occurs. Any variables available
>   at that line in the calling file will be available within the called
>   file, from that point forward. However, all functions and classes
>   defined in the included file have the global scope.

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.include.php

Para o seu código funcionar deveria ser assim:

Arquivo funcoes.php:

```
<?
   $tt = 'teste';
   function teste(){
       global $tt;
       return $tt;
   }
?>
Arquivo funcaoGenerica.php:

<?php
    function generic($sting){
        include_once($sting);

       return test();

    }
?>
Arquivo index.php:

<?
   include_once('/sistem/generics/funcaoGenerica.php');

   echo  generic('/sistem/exemploSistema/funcoes.php');
?>
```

Talvez em vez de uma função criar um arquivo com a lista de todos os arquivos que precisa. Algo tipo:

```
<?php

set_include_path(wamp/www/sistem/exemploSistema/);
set_include_path(wamp/www/sistem/generics/);

require(index.php);
require(funcoes.php);
require(funcaoGenerica.php);

?>
```

Nunca testei este tipo de arquivo, mas pode ser uma solução.

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa imaginar que o `include`, nada mais faz que incluir o conteúdo daquele arquivo naquele local, então se você esta dentro de uma função, estará sob o escopo dela.

Por exemplo, se você tiver:

```
<?php
    function generic(){
        include_once('funcoes.php');
    }
?>
```

E o arquivo **funcoes.php**:

```
<?
   $tt = 'teste';
   function teste(){
       global $tt;
       return $tt;
   }
?>
```

É **exatamente** a mesma coisa que:

```
<?php
    function generic(){
       $tt = 'teste';
       function teste(){
           global $tt;
           return $tt;
       }
    }
?>
```

Note que a variável `$tt` ficou no escopo da função `generic`, para acessa-la fora dessa função, seria preciso incluir no arquivo `funcoes.php` a declaração `global $tt;`

---

Por isso eu não recomendo que você siga com a ideia de incluir os arquivos dentro de funções, você terá inúmeros problemas de escopo, e será obrigado a declarar todas as variáveis utilizadas...

Crie um arquivo como: `includes.php` e relacione nele todos os arquivos a serem incluídos, será bem mais fácil, pode ter certeza...

---

**Edit:** Consegui criar uma forma de passar todas as variáveis do escopo da função para o global automaticamente:

```
function generic($string){
    include($string);
    foreach(get_defined_vars() as $key => $value) $GLOBALS[$key] = $value;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Você não esta conseguindo executar as funções pois seu include esta dando problema:

Está assim:

```
generic('/sistem/exemploSistema/funcoes');
```

Deveria ser assim:

```
 generic('/sistem/exemploSistema/funcoes.php');
```

Comment: não cara, eu estava tentando exemplificar o meu erro. Esse código eu inventei agora seguindo a mesma estrutura e a mesma lógica do sistema! Não há erros de sintexe, e sim de lógica.

Comment: eu repliquei o que voce fez e esta funcionando

Comment: fiz alteração no que não está funcionando na minha pergunta

Comment: Esta resposta corresponde à [primeira versão da pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/30405/1), onde havia um erro de digitação. É por isso que não dá pra colocar pseudo-code numa pergunta deste tipo, tem que ser o código real, @DouglasBernardino.

Comment: esse é um dos maiores problemas querem colocar um codigo qualquer e ter o resultado esperado ... quer ajuda precisa passar o máximo de informação possível