# Qual a diferença entre iniciar uma váriavel vazia e iniciar direto com o valor?

Tags: php, variáveis, estilo-de-codificação

Vejo em vários lugares coisas como:

```
$arr = [];

$var = '';

$var;

$var = null;
```

Qual a diferença entre iniciar a váriavel assim:

```
$var = '';

$var = 'teste';
```

E iniciar assim:

```
$var= 'teste';
```

Comment: Acredito que a unica diferença é linha a mais para processar, como o PHP não é uma linguagem tipada não faz diferença atribuir um valor a variável antes ou depois. Você pode usar dos dois modos de acordo com o que deseja fazer, mas o mais comum é criar uma variável e já atribuir um valor a ela

Comment: Relacionada: [Quais as implicações de não declarar variáveis em PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/841/91)

Comment: Cada linguagem de programação terá um comportamento expecífico para variávies inicializadas com valor ou não. Principalmente em linguagens tipadas e ou não tipadas.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Um motivo aceitável é evitar o `undefined`, por exemplo...

```
class teste {
  public $teste = '';

  public function mudar(){
    if(1 < 0){
      $this->teste = 'mudou';
    }
  }

  public function exibir(){
    echo $this->teste;
  }

}

$res = new teste();
$res->mudar();
$res->exibir();
```

Repare que em `mudar()`, o if não deu true, logo `teste` não foi definido, se eu não tivesse definido no começo da classe, em `exibir()` teríamos uma propriedade indefinida

Answer (score 9):

A pergunta na forma como foi apresentada não faz sentido porque em ambos está iniciando com valor.

O primeiro exemplo inicia com uma *string* cujo valor é nenhum caractere e depois muda para uma *string* com um texto.

```
$var = '';
$var = 'teste';
```

O segundo exemplo já inicia com o texto.

```
$var = 'teste';
```

Seria uma variável sem valor se fizesse:

```
$var;
$var = 'teste';
```

Mas note que nestes exemplo é sempre um desperdício porque está declarando ou inicializando a variável, não usando aquilo para nada e depois muda seu valor, ou seja, então era só ter feito a última linha. Faria sentido se tivesse operações com a variável em um estado e depois mudar o estado.

Se não vai usar a variável não a crie. Deixe para fazer isto quando precisa dela.

Declarar uma variável sem valor é o mesmo que não declarar.

Veja:

```
echo gettype($var) . ' - |' . $var . '| - ';
$var;
echo gettype($var) . ' - |' . $var . '| - ';
$var = '';
echo gettype($var) . ' - |' . $var . '| - ';
$var = 'teste';
echo gettype($var) . ' - |' . $var . '| - ';
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/cbVqON). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/fqqjxnbt-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Syntax/InitializingVariable.php).

Answer (score 3):

No caso de definir a variável com o valor de `array`, é importante a definição, pois mesmo podendo definir diretamente como `array`, se você definir como outro tipo de valor pode gerar erros.

Por exemplo, assim daria certo:

```
$a = [];

$a[] = 1;

$b[] = 1;
```

Assim daria erro:

```
$c = ' ';

$c[] = 1; // PHP Fatal error:  [] operator not supported for strings

$d = new stdClass;

$d[] = 2; // Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array
```

Olhando os exemplos acima, percebemos que os valores do `array` pode ser definido mesmo não declarando a variável anteriormente, mas percebemos que isso pode ser um grande problema caso use uma variável com tipos diferentes acidentalmente.

Eu tenho pra mim que é sempre importante explicitar o que se está fazendo.

Answer (score 0):

Se você por acaso iniciar uma variavel desse modo:

```
$x;
```

Ela tem de ser inicializada em algum lugar pois pode possuir lixo de memoria. Por exemplo:

```
$i = $x + 1;
```

Voce nao sabe o que pode sair dai pois ela nao teve valor inicial. Algumas linguagens de programação nao permitem isso, entao cuidado.

Caso seja assim:

```
$x = '';
```

Algumas linguagens vão entender como a variavel sendo null, outras nem suportam.

```
$x = null;
```

Este caso é auto explicativo, você nao atribui nenhum real, mas diz que ela existe e ja inicializada. Cuidado pois é diferente de 0.

E se voce declarar com algum valor prévio, é um valor inicial. Pode ser alterado depois caso a linguagem permita.

```
$x  = 'teste';
```

Cuidado neste caso ao atribuir outra string que use " " ao inves de ' ', no php sao coisas diferentes e pode gerar algum erro.

Answer (score 0):

Se você declarar uma variével 
`$var;`
e utilizá-la em alguma parte do código sem que seja atribuído valor, o lixo da memória pode fazer com que o programa estoure um erro ou pior, pode criar um comportamento inadequado que será difícil de ser detectado.